# php how to find index of element in array value of which is less than number?

Tags: php, arrays

Say, there is an array and a number:

```
$values = ['a'=>10, 'b'=>20, 'c'=>30];
$num = 25;
```

How can I find an index of the array element the value of which is less than the number?

In the above example it will be the 'b' index of which is 1.

Comment: What steps would use to do this manually? Write the 'algorithm' down on paper. Good. Now turn it into code.

Comment: Here is a slightly different way to frame the problem: "What is the index of the *first* element that has a *higher (or equal)* value?". The first value 'lower' is thus found at the 'previous index', should one exist.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I thought I got it above, but still need to work out what to do in case the number equals the last element

Comment: ok, finally got it!

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the array by the values then loop through it until a number is hit above the `$num`. Here is a quick example:

```
$values = ['a'=>10, 'b'=>20, 'c'=>30];
$num = 25;
$sortedValues = $values;
asort($sortedValues);
while (($current = current($sortedValues)) !== false && $current < $num) {
    $lastValue = key($sortedValues);
    next($sortedValues);
}
echo $lastValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
$values = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>20, 'c'=>30, 'd'=>40, 'e'=>50];
$num = 55;
$i = null;
foreach ($values as $k => $v){
    if ($v == $num){
        echo $v;
        break;
    }
    elseif ($num >= 1 && $v > $num){
        echo $values[$i];
        break;
    }
    elseif ($num > end($values)){
        echo end($values);
        break;
    }
    $i = $k;
}
```

Comment: So, you get "an index of the last element less or equal(but not last) to given number, if exists"? Looks little different with question wording. Is also echoing for debug purposes?

Comment: I didn't think about what happens if the number equals the last or if it's greater that that. I've changed the code. Yes, the echo is for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

May be `array_filter` can be some more handy:

```
$values = ['a'=>1, 'b'=>20, 'c'=>30, 'd'=>40, 'e'=>50];
$num = 45;

// filter items less than $num
$lesser = array_filter($values, function($v) use($num) { 
  return $v < $num;
});

// get necessary item/index from filtered, last for example
$lesserKeys = array_keys($lesser);
$lastOfLessKey = end($lesserKeys);
$lastOfLess = end($lesser);
var_dump($lastOfLessKey, $lastOfLess); // d 40
```

Comment: The disadvantage of using `array_filter()` for a task like this is that it cannot `break` early.  Assuming the OP is expecting only one "best" qualifier, then a classic `foreach()` with a `break` is the best way forward.

Comment: Agree =) It can be also some sort of binary search, but what our input size?

Answer (score -1):

```
    $values = ['a'=>10, 'b'=>20, 'c'=>30];
    $num = 25;

foreach($value as $key => $val){
    if( (int) $val == (int) $num){
         echo 'this is what you are searching. key is: '.$key.', value is: '.$val;
}


}
```